# How to configure datasource in TomEE with JDBC driver in private maven repo?

Tags: maven, tomcat, datasource, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I'm attempting to use Tomcat (TomEE) to run a REST service that will return some data from some SQL queries (Oracle).  I've installed TomEE 7.0.1, which uses Tomcat 8.5.3.

The JDBC driver is available from a private enterprise maven repo.  I'd prefer to get it from there, as opposed to storing it locally.  I noticed at http://tomee.apache.org/configuring-datasources.html , there is the possible notation of "mvn:g:a:v" for the "classpath" attribute.  However, I don't see any way to configure the Maven repositories this will reference.  How do I tell it to look in a particular repo for this?

My Resource definition in "conf/tomee.xml" looks something like this:

```
  <Resource id="jdbc/sus2" type="DataSource"
        maxActive="5" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:1521:<sid>"
        username="<user>" password="<password>"/>
```

Does this look correct (except for the fact that I'm not getting it from maven yet)?  I find the Tomcat docs confusing, with respect to the required syntax for this.  It's not clear whether a pure XML syntax is required, or a mixed XML/property syntax.

I haven't written the code to reference this datasource yet, but if I start the instance, should I see any default output that will show Tomcat connecting to this datasource?  If it doesn't show this by default, is there a way to turn this on?

Comment: I'm still having issues with the JNDI lookup, but I'm going to post my current related issue separately.

Answer (score 1):

For reference this thread got started on tomee list as well and got more answers: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Define-datasource-reference-JDBC-driver-and-see-init-in-console-td4679582.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the sample below for using JDBC driver as a database resource.

```
<Resource name="jdbcds" auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   username="hr" 
   password="hr" 
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))" />
```